# How to get labels of array on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I tried to get labels of array on AgensGraph?

But, It returns a error about type conversion.

How can I get labels of array?

```
agens=# match (n:o) with collect(n) as n return labels(n[0]);
ERROR:  cannot cast type jsonb to vertex
agens =# match (n:o{id:1}) return labels(n);
 labels 
--------
 ["o"]
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on array processing of AgensGraph.

function "collect" converts all data-types to json.

And It is impossible to revert data-types.

```
agens =# match (n:o) with collect(n) as n return n[0];
                           n                            
--------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": "3.1", "tid": "(0,1)", "properties": {"id": 1}}
(1 row)

agens =# match (n:o{id:1}) return n;
        n        
-----------------
 o[3.1]{"id": 1}
(1 row)
```

Use "array_agg" instead of "collect".

```
agens =# match (n:o) with array_agg(n) as n return n[0];
        n        
-----------------
 o[3.1]{"id": 1}
(1 row)

agens =# match (n:o) with array_agg(n) as n return labels(n[0]);
 labels 
--------
 ["o"]
(1 row)
```